# Printing a message every minute in python

Tags: python, time

I am working to print out a message to the terminal once every minute. I cannot use time.sleep() because there are other things that need to continue to run. Here is the what I have so far, but I am sure that there is a more legitimate what of doing this

```
startTime = time.time()
.
..
...
code to run other things
...
..
.     
endTime= time.time()
epochTime = int(endTime - startTime)

print ('epochTime: ' + str(epochTime))


if (epochTime % 60):
    print ('A minute has passed')
```

Please advice on my best course of acton here

Comment: do you need this while your program is running or just every minute in general?

Comment: I need it every minute while my program is running

Comment: @metatoaster thankyou, but I cannot have my program sleep for a full second, which is why i reckoned it is not a duplicate of the linked question. Please advice if Im mistaken here

Comment: @Veejay there is a solution in my original linked answer that provide a non-blocking method, which the second duplicate question also referenced.